# Basic topology proof regarding injection being equal to intersection property for two subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, injective-module

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$. Show that the statement $$f(C \cap D) = f(C) \cap f(D)$$ for all possible choices of $C, D, \subseteq 
X$ is equivalent to $f$ being injective.

So first I restated the statement by using if and only if instead of equivalent and tried to prove it from there. Should I approach this by letting there be some element $c \in C$ and $d \in D$ such that $f(c) = f(d)$ and use that to prove that the intersection $f(C) \cap f(D)$is nonempty? I'm having some trouble determining which approach to take on this problem, any tips would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just did, thanks

Comment: You can find the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Image_of_Intersection_under_Injection)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Assume that $f$ is not injective (i.e. you can find $c\neq d$ in $X$ such that $f(c)=f(d)$) and then you just need to find some particular $C$ and $D$ that do not verify the equality above ($C$ and $D$ will be small).

Assume that $f$ is injective, take $C$ and $D$ two subsets and show that $f(C\cap D)\subseteq f(C)\cap f(D)$ (easy, works even when $f$ is not necessary injective) and $f(C)\cap f(D)\subseteq f(C\cap D)$ (here your need injectivity).

Comment: Okay so I've finished the second part. Could you elaborate more on finding the particular C and D?

Comment: Ok, $C$ and $D$ should be both sets with one element.

Comment: It can be any one element?

Comment: @JamesBlake $C=\{x\}$, $D=\{y\}$. Now you should do a clever choice of $x$ and $y$ such that $C$ and $D$ does not verify the equality.

Comment: Could I do like 0 and 1?

Comment: @JamesBlake, remember that we assumed that $f$ was not injective...

Comment: I'm sorry it's just very difficult for me to come up with x and y when f is just a general function. So we want two different elements that results two different results after f?

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood when you said "the equality above" which equality were you referring to?

Comment: @JamesBlake $f(C\cap D)=f(C)\cap f(D)$.

Comment: Yup I was definitely looking at the wrong equality. Let me retry now haha

Comment: Could I choose x and y so that f(x) = f(y)?